# Debuging in PhpStorm using xdebug ignores breakpoints

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I am having issues with debuging in PhpStorm. I have setup the xdebug and it seems to work OK but my breakpoints are never hit and keep getting ignored.

Here is the setup.

Xdebug: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

The PhpStorm's listening is turned on:

[image]

And the debug validation tool says everything is working fine too:

[image]

Chrome extension does make the connection when debug button is pressed:

[image]

BUT no breakpoints get hit :(

[image]

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: *"Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?"* Last 2 screenshots clearly show that you are doing **JavaScript debugging** and not PHP... https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: try checking option  breakpoint at first line in the xdebug settings and restart debugger